# Getting singleton services in IActionFilter

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-6.0

This is probably a basic question, but I can't find a good reference.

I have a simple filter and it executes fine.

```cs
     public class MyFilter: IActionFilter
        {
            public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
            {
            }
    
            public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
            {
                
                // this fails since my singleton service is not in the collection
                context.HttpContext.RequestServices
                     .GetRequiredService<IConnectionMultiplexer>();
            }
        }
```

When the filter executes and I consult context.HttpContext.RequestServices, I only find services that were registered as scoped. Is it possible for me to get a service registered as a singleton (which is what my IConnectionMultiplexer is)?

What I'm trying to do is execute a DB lookup as part of the pipeline, to augment the response's headers with my customer headers. Alternatives welcome as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a constructor for the filter and can access the singleton service directly right?

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<DemoService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<CustomFilter>();
```

And in the filter.

```
public class CustomFilter : IActionFilter
{
    private readonly DemoService _demoService;

    public CustomFilter(DemoService demoService)
    {
        _demoService = demoService;
    }
    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {   
    }

    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, using this way it does work, but I was trying to do it programmatically based on code path at point of use, so I'd like to understand why my original attempt didn't work. But for now, I'll use this approach.